# JavaFX Animation - How to animate move in Z direction

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-2

I have the following code to animate an 3D B747 Model moving on the runway, to visualise the takeoff I need to set a new MoveTo path towards Z-axis (depth) (eg. towards the sky) however there isn't any Z-axis-config among any of the path elements.

```
Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(-240, 0)); // Initial x-axis pos
    path.getElements().add(new HLineTo(0)); // This x-axis (horizontal)
    // path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(Z-Direction)) // Takeoff?
```

Thanks in adanvce!

Comment: Hmm, this might make a good feature request, perhaps raise it for discussion on the [openjfx-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) JavaFX developer  mailing list.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the internal implementation of Path delegates to a class called Path2D, which only works with 2D co-ordinates.  A fully realized implementation of this would delegate to a Path3D class which is 3D aware and handles additional constructs such as ArcTo as well as MoveTo, however such a class does not currently exist in the internal JavaFX 8 implementation.

Comment: Perhaps, see if a third party library such as [F(x)yz](http://birdasaur.github.io/FXyz/) contains some of the functionality you need (I haven't looked into it in detail to check it's feature set).

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the support! I'm already using Fxyz library. I will see if it can help.